# How to update GLib repository to at 2.76.3?

Tags: 22.04, repository, glib

A continuation from [Need to update GLib library but the current version is assumed as the newest (it's not)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470057/need-to-update-glib-library-but-the-current-version-is-assumed-as-the-newest-it)

So I would like to update the GLib (glib-2.0) repository to the latest version 2.76.3 (or at least  2.74) since, as I understand, the official one is only 2.72.4 on my Ubuntu.
What are the commands to do so?

Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS

Sorry if the question seems stupid, I'm completely new to working with libraries and repositories

Comment: IMHO it would be **far** simpler to upgrade your OS to one that provides the desired glib-2.0 version - Ubuntu 22.10 has [2.74.0-3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/libglib2.0-dev) and Ubuntu 23.04 has [2.76.1-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/libglib2.0-dev). Or stick with the version you have and follow the tutorial's advice: *"For GLib versions older than 2.74 you will need to replace G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS with G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE in this example, and others in this documentation."*